# How to implement NTT( Number theoretic transform)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, fast-fourier-transform

I am having tough time while implementing NTT.
After reading lot of tutorials on FFT and NTT from http://www.apfloat.org/ntt.html, http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/43499
and some others, I have implemented NTT taking advantage of Fermats theory while choosing the modulo prime.
But still I think I am missing something as invNTT(NNT(a)) is not coming out as 'a'.

Please have a look at my implementation.

```
package NumberTheory;

public class NTT {

public static void main(String args[]){
    long[] ans = new long[] {1,2,4,5};
    ans = NTT(ans,false);
    print(ans);
    System.out.println("-------");
    ans = invNTT(ans);
    print(ans);
}

public static long[] modPowNeg(long mod, long a){
    if(a == 0)
        return new long[] {a,1,0};
    else{
        long tmp[] = modPowNeg(a,mod%a);
        long d = tmp[0],x=tmp[2],y=tmp[1]-((mod/a)*tmp[2]);
        return new long[] {d,x,y};
    }
}

public static long[] invNTT(long[] a){
    long[] ans = NTT(a,true);
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        ans[i] = ans[i]/(a.length);
    return ans;
}

public static long modPow(long a,long n,long mod){
    if(n==1)
        return a;
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    long tempRes = modPow(a,n/2,mod);
    tempRes = (tempRes*tempRes)%mod;
    if(n%2==1)
        tempRes = (tempRes*a)%mod;
    return tempRes;
}


public static long[] NTT(long[] a, boolean inverse){
    if(a.length==1)
        return a;
    int len = a.length, k = len/2;
    long p = (long)Math.pow(2, k)+1;
    print(a);
    System.out.println("p="+p);
    long even[] = new long[k];
    long odd[] = new long[k];
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<k;i++){
        even[i]=a[j++];
        odd[i]=a[j++];
    }
    long[] evenNTT = NTT(even,inverse);
    long[] oddNTT = NTT(odd,inverse);
    long res[] = new long[len];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        long root1 = inverse?modPowNeg(p,modPow(2,i,p))[2]:modPow(2,i,p);
        long root2 = inverse?modPowNeg(p,modPow(2,i+k,p))[2]:modPow(2,i+k,p);
        System.out.println(i+" and "+(i+k)+" th roots "+root1+" "+root2);
        res[i] = evenNTT[i]+(root1*oddNTT[i]);
        res[k+i] = evenNTT[i]+(root2*oddNTT[i]);
    }
    print(res);
    return res;
}

public static void print(long a[]){
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    System.out.println();
}

}
```

Comment: It seems there might be a mathematical question connected with your project, but it will require clarification on your part to bring that out.  Merely giving some code and reporting that it doesn't work as you expect it to, is not a Question, and for it to be an on-topic Question here requires a fairly clear connection to a mathematical topic.  Code debugging anywhere on StackExchange requires a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree I am asking a debugging question. At the same time I think my question satisfies http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please let me know If I am providing not minimal or not complete or not verifiable example. I am providing an example a= {1,2,4,5} in my code. I am new to asking questions on math.stackexchange @hardmath